# Yii modules internationalization

Tags: php, yii, module, internationalization

> **Yii Doc:**
>   Modules can be nested in unlimited
>   levels. That is, a module can contain
>   another module which can contain yet
>   another module. We call the former
>   parent module while the latter child
>   module. Child modules must be declared
>   in the modules property of their
>   parent module, like we declare modules
>   in the application configuration shown
>   as above.

I try to create myltilingual application using **Yii::t()** function:

> **Yii Doc:**
>   And when using Yii::t() to translate
>   an extension message, the following
>   format should be used, instead: `Yii::t('Xyz.categoryName', 'message to be translated')`

I translate modules messages with `Yii::t('MyModule.source', 'Test');` it works for modules.
But not works for submodules `Yii::t('MyModule.SubModule.source', 'Test');`
**The question is:**
How to define source path for SubModule in Module when messages stored in:
`/protected/modules/MyModule/modules/SubModule/messages/`

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use `Yii::t` wrong.

The path for the `CPhpMessageSource` (first parameter of `Yii::t`) should be the module *in which the call to `Yii::t` appears*. It doesn't matter if that module is aggregated inside another module.

So in your example, you should use

```
Yii::t('SubModule.source', 'Test');
```

and place the messages in `/protected/modules/SubModule/messages/`.

If you need the message to change based on whether the translation is performed from inside a submodule, add parameters to the message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is not possible to do with CPhpMessageSource , you have to extend and create your own message class .

You have to modify your configuration file i.e. **config/main.php**  as well.

```
'components'=>array(
    ...........
    'messages' => array(
        'class' => 'MyPhpMessageSource',
    ),
    .............
```

and here is the sample MyPhpMessageSource.php that works for your needs.

```
class MyPhpMessageSource extends CPhpMessageSource {

private $_files=array();

protected function getMessageFile($category,$language)
{
    if(!isset($this->_files[$category][$language]))
    {
        $parts = explode('.', $category);
        $count = count($parts);

        if( $count > 1 ) {
            $filePath = '';
            $moduleClass=$parts[$count-2];

            $class=new ReflectionClass($moduleClass);
            $filePath .= dirname($class->getFileName()).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

            /*
            for($i=0; $i<$count-1; $i++) {
                $moduleClass=$parts[$i];

                if($i == 0) {
                    $class=new ReflectionClass($moduleClass);
                    $filePath .= dirname($class->getFileName()).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
                } else
                    $filePath .= $moduleClass.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            }
            */

            $filePath .= 'messages' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $language . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $parts[$count-1] . '.php';

            echo "$filePath<br/>";
            $this->_files[$category][$language] = $filePath;
        }
        else
            $this->_files[$category][$language]=$this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$language.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$category.'.php';
    }
    return $this->_files[$category][$language];
}
}
```