# Access a module's translation from differernt modules in Yii

Tags: yii, module, internationalization, translation

I really need some help.

I have created two modules in my project: **admin** and **account**.
In my **admin** module I have **User model**.

I have managed to translate my **admin module** using following structure:

```
modules
   -admin
       -models
       -controllers
       -views
       -messages
         - en
           user.php  
         - ru
           user.php
       -AdminModule.php
```

and used following expression `Yii::t("adminModule.user","Username")` to output my translated message.

However this doesn't work if I'm trying to access **User model** from **account module**. Fields are not translated and application even troughs an exception: 
`include(adminModule.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Seems like I'm not able to include my **admin** module. So I have tried to import it as follows within my account/AccountModule.php

```
 public function init() {

    $this->setImport(array(
        'account.models.*',
        'account.components.*',            
        'application.modules.admin.models.*',
        'application.modules.admin.messages.*',
    ));
}
```

In my main **config** file I added following lines of code as it has been suggested. 
But no help,I still have the same exception.

```
'sourceLanguage' => 'en',
'language' => 'ru',
```

I've tried lots of stuff suggested in the following resources

1. [Yii modules internationalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853909/yii-modules-internationalization)
2. http://www.rymland.org/post/27?title=Enforcing+translation+of+message+in+Yii
3. [yii use message in module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964834/yii-use-message-in-module)

Also read Yii documentation

1. http://yiiframework.ru/doc/guide/ru/topics.i18n

But yet nothing helped me.

If someone has some ideas, kindly ask you for your assistance,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `Yii::t("admin.user","Username")`? As far as I know this should be exactly named after the module name definition which is in this case 'admin' not 'adminModule'.

Comment: Yes I tried that, that doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was pretty simple.
I was trying to import my **admin module** in a wrong way:

```
public function init() {

    $this->setImport(array(
        'account.models.*',
        'account.components.*',
        'application.modules.admin.models.*',
        'application.modules.*'
    ));
}
```

By doing this I have assumed that imported all my modules including **admin module**. But I was wrong.

Correct way is to use the following statement!

```
public function init() {
        ...
        'application.modules.admin.AdminModule'            
    ));
}
```